# Java reading/writing using modified DataInputStreams

Tags: java, io, fileinputstream, datainputstream

This is the sample I have to work with. I spent about 30 minutes but could not find anything comprehensive on how to use this class.

Let me explain what we have to work with. There is a database class which stores data on "Students" inside a linked list. From the main method we get students being added to the list using an add() method from the database class. The database class has methods to write and read the said files but alas I do not understand what to do now. The instructions state that:

1. A new file stream has to be opened.
2. "Should be buffered" - not sure what this implies
3. Included class StudentRecordReader should work with the said buffered

   ```
   public boolean readFromFile(String fileName){
       boolean success = false;
       Student s = null;
       try{
       //Need to open a file stream
       File file = new File(fileName);
       if(!file.exists()){
           file.createNewFile();
       }
       //Should be then buffered
       DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new           
       FileInputStream(file)));
       StudentRecordReader r;//this should work with a buffered stream
       r = new StudentRecordReader(in);
       r.close();
       }catch(IOException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
       }
   return success;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I think StudentRecordReader must open a buffered input stream

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(path)))
```

then read Student fields from file, eg

```
String name = dis.readUTF();
String address = dis.readUTF();
```

then create a Student based on this data

```
new Student(name, address);
```

then read next student...

Comment: That makes sense. My issue is mainly as to how it ties in with the method that calls it. How does one go about sending in the input stream?

Note I added the read method above.

Comment: After //Should be then buffered line you should add  new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

Comment: Last question. How would I read from the said stream of student records if I had an (InputStream in) passed in

Comment: You will pass InputStream to StudentReader (not DataInputStream) and create new DataInputStream(in) in StudentReader. BTW in your initial version it was like that, it seems

Comment: That is because I put a different class in there. We have two classes which we use. First is used to create the said stream. Second is used to process it. The one up there right now is the one which creates the stream. Or at least that is how I understand it now.

Comment: To create a file with Students you need to use DataOutputStream

Comment: Alright so Main calls readFromFile(Filename name);
readFromFile() creates a file or opens a file and creates an InputStream.
Then we make a StudentRecordReader and pass in the InputStream to that.
What classes or methods can I use to read the data? Sorry for this but  I am a very confused student who got all of a sudden thrown into all these streams etc.

Comment: I think createFile is wrong. If file does not exist - throw FileNotFoundException

Comment: We need to create a file if it doesn't exist.

Comment: I think this is StudentWriter's task